# Javascript Encode "ENQ" ASCII Character in USB Stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, libusb

I am using the Node-USB library: https://github.com/tessel/node-usb

In the output method

```
    transfer(data, callback(error)
    Perform a transfer to write data to the endpoint.)
```

I need to send 05 4d. Which is ENQ M.

If I do `.transfer("5M"` --- I get 35 4D
If I do `.transfer("ENQM"` -- I get 45 4E 51 4D

How do I get the transfer to encode ENQ M as 05 4d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENQ` in this sample doesn't mean the three letters `E`, `N` and `Q`. It refers to the Unicode control character ENQUIRY U+0005, which also happens to be 0x05 in ASCII.

To represent that in a string, use `\u0005`: `.transfer("\u0005M");`

For the sake of readability you could put that into a constant:

```
const ENQ = "\u0005";

// ...
foo.transfer(ENQ+"M");
```